# Hibernate/JPA - Collection of UUID can't determine data type when using IS NULL comparison

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using **Spring Boot** with **PostgreSQL JDBC 42.2.13** and **Hibernate 5.3.18.Final**, and it seems that when adding `IS NULL` check to a collection of UUIDs, Hibernate/PostgreSQL cannot determine the data type of the collection.

#### Entity

```java
class Element {
    @Column
    private UUID uuid;
}
```

#### Repository

```java
@Query("SELECT e FROM Element e WHERE (:uuids) IS NULL OR e.uuid IN (:uuids)")
    List<Element> findByUuidIn(@Param("uuids") Collection<UUID> uuids);
```

#### Query execution

```java
elementRepository.findByUuidIn(List.of(UUID.randomUUID())); // works fine!
elementRepository.findByUuidIn(null); // -> Throws exception
```

#### Parameters binding from trace logging

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [OTHER] - [null]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [OTHER] - [null]
```

#### Exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:103)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor582.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy398.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 114 common frames omitted
```

#### Temporary solution

Change the query parameter to String and cast the column type in query.

```java
@Query("SELECT e FROM Element e WHERE (:uuids) IS NULL OR CAST(e.uuid AS string) IN (:uuids)")
    List<Element> findByUuidIn(@Param("uuids") Collection<String> uuids);
```

```java
elementRepository.findByUuidIn(null); // works fine!
```

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
```

#### Question to the community

- Is there a way to provide a `null` collection of UUID as parameter and have the `IS NULL` check?
- Is it a bug in Hibernate that doesn't bind parameter type `UUID` and uses `OTHER` instead when using `null` collection as parameter?
- Is it a bug in PostgreSQL JDBC that doesn't determine the type of parameter when using `OTHER` type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hibernate has three [basic types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic) mapped to the `java.util.UUID`:

1. `org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType` is mapped to [binary data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-binary.html) (`bytea`)
2. `org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType` is mapped to `CHAR`, can also read `VARCHAR`
3. `org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType` is mapped to the PostgreSQL [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-uuid.html), through `Types#OTHER`, which complies to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver definition.

A lot of PostgreSQL types mapped to the `java.sql.Types.OTHER`, for example `org.postgresql.util.Pgobject` (*bit varying*), `org.postgresql.geometric.Pgpoint` (*point*), `org.postgresql.geometric.Pgbox` (*box*), `java.util.UUID` (*uuid*), ... (see [this](https://software.fujitsu.com/jp/manual/manualfiles/m150000/j2ul1738/08enz200/j1738-00-02-04-01.html)). So, PostgreSQL JDBC driver could not determine data type of parameter when you pass `null`.

#### Solutions

1. You can correct your query in the following way:

```java
@Query("SELECT e FROM Element e WHERE (:uuids) IS NULL OR CAST(e.uuid as org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType) IN (:uuids)")
List<Element> findByUuidIn(@Param("uuids") Collection<UUID> uuids);
```

It will allow you to use `Collection<UUID>` as passed parameter type. But, actually this is similar to your workaround, because it will generate the following sql:

```sql
select
   element0_.id as id1_2_ 
from TEST_SCHEMA.ELEMENT element0_ 
where  ? is null or cast(element0_.id as varchar(255)) in (?)
```

2. You can change your table's column definition:

```sql
create table ELEMENT
(
   id bytea,
   ...
);
```

Then map this column in the following way:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
public class Element
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Type(type = "uuid-binary") // This is pg-uuid by default for PostgreSQL82Dialect and higher
   private UUID id;

   // ...
}
```

and then you will be able to query it without any casting:

```java
Collection<UUID> uuids = null;

List<Element> elements = em.createQuery(
   "select e from Element e where (:uuids) is null or e.id in (:uuids)",
   Element.class)
.setParameter("uuids", uuids)
.getResultList();
```